# $e^{-in\theta}$ is bounded, but converges conditionally?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

So my question is 
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\ \left(\frac{2}{z-i}\right)^n$$
this series converges for all z lying inside the disk of radius $2$ centered at i.
My doubt here is, what happens at $|z-i|=2$.
Is it true that it diverges for every $\theta$ since this series

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ e^{-i\theta n}$$ can be derived if we take $z=i+2e^{i\theta}$ and does not converge for any theta i.e. no $z$ such that $|z-i|=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. There is no need to mention $e^{-in\theta}$ though. If $z=i+2w$, with $|w|=1$, then you get the series$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1w\right)^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{w^n},$$which diverges, since you don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{w^n}=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot José.

Comment: @ivanculet If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: of course José, I forgot about it.